# Perl hash Data::Dumper output

Tags: perl, shell, command-line, console

In Perl I need to analyze a huge hash, so I print it into a file using Data::Dumper module. Because it is a huge file, it is very hard to read. Is it possible somehow to print the output into a log file.

Comment: My console or else command prompt is just displaying the most recent values rather than the whole output.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You print output to a file, but the file gets too large so that it is hard to read. And you wonder if you can print the output to a file instead? How is that different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the output anywhere you want. If you already have a log file open in your program, you can just

```
print $log Dumper $myhash;
```

But in general there is nothing special about log files. If you don't have one open you can just open a temporary file.

```
open my $temp, '>', 'myhash.txt' or die $!;
print $temp Dumper $myhash;
close $temp;
```

and you will have a new text file `myhash.txt` that contains the data structure.

By the way, the [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data%3a%3aDump) module is more recent and tends to generate more compact and more readable output. If you want to try it (it may need installing on your system) use this

```
use Data::Dump 'dump';

open my $temp, '>', 'myhash.txt' or die $!;
print $temp dump $myhash;
close $temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having to modify your script for a temporary change, redirect the output to a file:

```
perl your-script.pl > output.txt
```

or pipe it into a pager:

```
perl your-script.pl | less
```